# How to enable WLAN on Ubuntu after boot?

Tags: boot, networking

Unbelievable, but I'm trying since months (since the update to bionic) and for several hours to get Ubuntu to automatically start my WiFi after startup.

Just starting the configured network. No plug and play, no DHCP, no other crap. Just trying to start the wireless network configured correctly in `/etc/network/interfaces.d/wlan0` with a static IP address. Just starting it like it works when I go to the console and enter `ifup wlan0`. Just the way it have been working since decades on Linux.

I don't care about NetworkManager, network-manager, networking, netplan or the other 25 alternative ways to configure network cards. I just want to start the fucking network card automatically after booting the system.

Is this really impossible on a "modern" system?

Comment: I feel with you, bro. These new "Linux" ways of doing it are miserable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seams to be fixed with the latest Cosmic update.

I'm curious how long it will work until the next update kills it again.